# How to retrieve data from firebase using the key value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crud

I am working on a web application and I purely used javascript to store read and delete data. So it's a blog-type application in which I currently am working on, and my database schema is like the following picture.

[image]

Now the problem is I want to retrieve values of posts (like description, imageurl, task) by key value postCategory which is "software engineering".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the equalTo

```
postsRef.orderByChild("postCategory").equalTo("software engineering").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
    System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }

  // ...
});
```